# "An error occurred: GraphQlDsUsersRole - Syntax errors in policy." when using serverless-appsync-plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, aws-appsync

Following alongside the tutorials, but changing some semantic things, I'm getting this error from serverless when I deploy:

`An error occurred: GraphQlDsUsersRole - Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: 4b486514-e57d-4828-9edc-f9150d8806b4; Proxy: null).`

Doing a search on my directory, this role seems to be autogenerated into the .serverless file. How is this generated, and what could I have done to mess it up?

My serverless.yml file:

```
service: graphql-api

plugins:
  - serverless-appsync-plugin
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - ./node_modules/**

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-1

custom:
  stage: dev
  appSync:
    name: ${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}
    authenticationType: API_KEY
    mappingTemplates:
      - dataSource: Users
        type: Query
        field: getUsers
        request: 'getUsers-request-mapping-template.txt'
        response: 'getUsers-response-mapping-template.txt'
    schema: schema.graphql
    dataSources:
      - type: AMAZON_DYNAMODB
        name: Users
        description: User Table
        config:
          tableName: { Ref: UserTable }
          serviceRoleARN: { Fn::GetAtt: [AppSyncDynamoDBServiceRole, Arn]}
          iamRoleStatements:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'dynamodb:*'
              Resources:
                - 'arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:table/Users'
                - 'arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:table/Users/*'

resources:
  - ${file(resources/roles.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/dynamodb.yml)}
```

My roles.yml file:

```
  AppSyncDynamoDBServiceRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      RoleName: "Dynamo-${self:service}-Role"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "appsync.amazonaws.com"
                - "dynamodb.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "Dynamo-${self:service}-Policy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "dynamodb:Query"
                  - "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
                  - "dynamodb:GetItem"
                  - "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
                  - "dynamodb:PutItem"
                  - "dynamodb:Scan"
                  - "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
                Resource:
                  - "arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:table/Users"
                  - "arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:table/Users/*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response. Not sure if you found a solution yet, but I will answer anyway if that helps anyone

I notice 2 things here:

- `serviceRoleARN` is misspelled. It should be `serviceRoleArn`
- `serviceRoleArn` and `iamRoleStatements` are mutually exclusive. `serviceRoleArn` takes the ARN of a full already-existing role, while `iamRoleStatements` auto-generates the role for you with the provided policy statement. When both are provided, `serviceRoleArn` takes precedence.

So here, what what used was `iamRoleStatements` (because `serviceRoleArn` was misspelled).

The name of the generated resource confirms that: `GraphQlDsUsersRole`

As for why the policy is malformed, this is because `Resource` is misspelled too.
It has to be singular (even if you pass an array).